# User-level access to the FieldPermissions object

Tags: permissions, fields, permission-sets

Is it possible to give individual users read-only access to the FieldPermissions object?
Right now, as an admin, I am able to query the object:

> SELECT Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, SobjectType FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SobjectType='Contact'

But other users are not. Ideally, I would like to be able to read/write data in my application based on user permissions, but I'm currently unable to do so because of these access restrictions.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Do the users need to see FieldPermissions for other users, or just for themselves. If it's just for themselves, you can use a field describe call to see if they have access on it.

Comment: It's just for themselves. I looked into the field describe API and that worked perfectly (I'm currently checking the "createable" and "updateable" properties for each field, but it also seems like fields the user doesn't have access to just won't be returned in the API response). Thanks for your help!